# Persistent string present while using read.csv or fread

Tags: r

I've been searching for similar problems but I can't find anything helpful.

I'm trying to open a portion of a big csv file with

```
#choosing a certain number of variables from more than 250 available in the file

resources<-c("P13_2_1","P13_3_1","P13_2_2",...)
v <- fread("file.csv", select = resources, header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8"
```

After the file is opened, wherever there shoul be NA there's blank cells. However, when I try to see whats in any of the blank cells, i see this

```
v$P13_2_1[2]
[1] "\r"
```

Similarly, the header of every column seems fine in the viewer of R Studio but when I try to see them in the console, there's the same \r attached.

The problem is present using both, read.csv and fread and I've tried to modify the quote and na.string arguments.

I would like to get rid of the "\r" and posibly subtitute it with NA